# xpath for qualified attributes

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm using XPATH 1.0 to fetch some nodes from an XML document which uses a default namespace on the root and on nodes with attributes.  The `attributeFormDefault = "qualified"` is set on the schema.

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://example.com/transaction">
    <someElement/>
    <collection>
        <value p0:Name="SomeName" xmlns:p0="http://example.com/transaction">some value</value>
        <value p1:Name="SomeOtherName" xmlns:p1="http://example.com/transaction">some other value</value>
    </collection>
    <differentCollection>
        <value p2:Name="SomeName" xmlns:p2="http://example.com/transaction">not this one</value>
    </differentCollection>
</Transaction>
```

My aim is to get the `/Transaction/collection/value[@Name='SomeName']` node.

The only solution I've found so far seems a little broad:

```
//*[@*='SomeName']
```

I could also get the entire collection of `<value>` nodes by using:

```
//*[local-name()='value']
```

With the namespace restriction in mind, is there a cleaner, more precise way get the node I'm after? 3rd party javascript libraries are not an option.

---

EDIT

Thanks for the quick responses.  I'll note here that by adding a default namespace prefix, solved the xpath query expressions:

```
<t:Transaction xmlns:t="http://example.com/transaction">
```

Now i can do:

```
/t:Transaction/t:collection/t:value[@t:Name='SomeName']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want to select the following:

```
/t:Transaction/t:collection/t:value[@t:Name = 'SomeName']
```

…given that you have declared `t` as the prefix for the `"http://example.com/transaction"` namespace prior to evaluating the XPath expression.

For the sample XML you show you could compress it to `//t:value[@t:Name = 'SomeName']`.

In any case, you do not get to ignore the namespaces in your input document. `attributeFormDefault` is a red herring in the issue.

---

How to define selection namespaces depends on the API you use to evaluate the XPath expression.

Browser-integrated APIs support a namespace resolver function that maps the prefixes used in the expression to the according namespace URIs. Further reading: [MDN: Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript).

A simple resolver would look like this:

```
function nsResolver(prefix) {
    var ns = {
        t: "http://example.com/transaction",
    };
    return ns[prefix] || null;
}
```

Note that namespace prefixes in the XPath don't have to agree with namespace prefixes in the XML. The URIs they point to, however, must agree.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to skirt namespaces, [follow best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29674536/290085) and bind a prefix to the namespace and then write your XPath using namespace prefixes:

1. Bind `p0` to `http://example.com/transaction` using the mechanism
   provided by your XPath processor.
2. Then leverage the namespace prefix in the XPath expression:

   ```
   /p0:Transaction/p0:collection/p0:value[@p0:Name='SomeName']
   ```